# CommaDelimitedList for ACM Subject Alternative Names

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Writing a CFN for ACM, but don't know the difference between
`CommaDelimitedList` and `List<CommaDelimitedList>`

According to the aws doc
https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html

CommaDelimitedList
An array of literal strings that are separated by commas. The total number of strings should be one more than the total number of commas. Also, each member string is space trimmed.
For example, users could specify "test,dev,prod", and a Ref would result in ["test","dev","prod"].

So what is the difference between them

```
  SubjectAlternativeName:
    Type: List<CommaDelimitedList>
    Description: Alternative sub-domain names that will be covered in your certificate.
```

So in the actual input when creating the resource, what should be the data for correct type?

Is below correct? for `CommaDelimitedList` or ?
[image]

Comment: Try and let us know what did you find.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to my question:

They can be used interchangeably

`List<CommaDelimitedList>` and `CommaDelimitedList`

Also '`List<String>`'

In term of the input for these types `List<CommaDelimitedList>` and `CommaDelimitedList`

Example as below
[image]